# Why is $O(n;k)$ not connected, and has four connected components?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, linear-algebra, lie-groups

Why is $O(n;k)$ not connected and has four connected components when $nk\ge 1$?
Here $O(n;k) =\{A\in GL(n+k,\mathbb{R}) \mid A^{T}GA=G\}$

where 
$G=\begin{pmatrix}
1&&&&&\\
&\ddots& & & &\\
&&1&& &\\
&& &-1& &\\
&& & &\ddots &\\
&& & & &-1
\end{pmatrix}$,

with $n$ instances of $1$, and $k$ instances of $-1$.

Comment: where n and k are non-zero. If k=0, get an orthogonal group O(n) with two connected components.

Comment: This was a reasonable question with an interesting and useful answer, you could have migrated it to MathSE instead of closing it.

Comment: @YCor please paste the interlinkage.

Comment: I voted to reopen and have now voted to migrate to math.se, per @YCor's comment.

Comment: Well, it has been closed by a set $A$ of 5 users, reopened by a set $B$ of 5 users (after my previous comment), and closed (instead of migrated) by a set $C$ of 5 users. While $A\cap (B\cup C)$ is empty, $B\cap C$ consists of 3 people: myself, j.c., and Francois Ziegler. Since it has not been migrated, at least 3 closing votes were not for migration, and hence it includes at least one person who voted for reopening, and certainly not me. Why such an absurd pair of votes? (when I voted for migration, one vote was cast for being "unclear"!!)

Comment: I too am puzzled by this turn of events. I have flagged the question for migration by the moderators.

Comment: Ah, here's the deal: it can't be migrated (blocked from asking).

Comment: Also the user recently posted a mathematics question at MO meta.

Comment: @ToddTrimble what does "blocked from asking" mean? I asked this on meta as the answer (and all the discussion concerning this) can prove relevant to other MO questions: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3699/blocked-migration-to-mathse

Comment: @j.c. thanks for flagging! I suggest to pursue the discussion on meta https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3699/blocked-migration-to-mathse

Comment: Since $O(n,k)$ as defined is closed under transposes, the group $O(n,k)\cap O(n+k)=O(n)\times O(k)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $O(n,k)$. Therefore, the number of connected components of $O(n,k)$ is the same as that of $O(n)\times O(k)$, and this is $2\times 2=4$.

Comment: @Venkataramana Why $O(n，k)\cap O(n+k)=O(n)\times O(k)$？

Comment: @user123325, the intersection preserves the quadratic forms with plus and minus signs being a subgroup of $O(n,k)$ and preserves the quadratic form with only pluses being a subgroup of $O(n+k)$. Hence it preserves the sum and difference of the quadratic forms and their null spaces, Thus it preserves $R^n$ and $R^k$, hence it lies in $O(n)\times O(k)$

Answer (score 12):

To see that there are at least four connected components, write $A$ blockwise:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} B & C \\ D & E \end{pmatrix},\qquad B\in M_n, E\in M_k.$$
Then $A^TGA=G$ decomposes as three identities, among which
$$B^TB=I_n+C^TC,\qquad E^TE=I_k+D^TD.$$
The matrix $B^TB$ is thus larger (in the sense of symmetric matrices) than $I_n$, hence positive definite. There follows that $B$ is always non-singular. The same is true for the block $E$. Now form the map
$$f:O(n;k)\rightarrow\{\pm1\}^2,\qquad f(A)=({\rm sgn}(\det B),{\rm sgn}(\det E)).$$
From above, this is a continuous function (the determinants don't vanish). When $nk\ge 1$, it is obviously onto (consider diagonal elements of the group). Hence $O(n;k)$ has at least as many connected components as the target $\{\pm\}^2$, that is four.

To see that there are exactly four connected components, you have to prove that $O(n;k)$ is stable under the polar decomposition. Next prove that $O(n;k)\cap SPD_{n+k}$ is homeomorphic (through the exponential map) to a vector space, and check that $O(n;k)\cap O(n+k)\sim O(n)\times O(k)$. Since $O(n)$ and $O(k)$ have two connected components, you are done.

**Remark**. The map $f$ defined above is a group homomorphism !

**Reference**: see my book *Matrices. Springer-Verlag GTM 216.* In the second edition, it Chapter 10.

Comment: What is the meaning of CCs ？

Comment: @user123325 CC = Connected Component.